# React 16 Radio Button onChange not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried several solutions to the following forms but had no luck. I want to send the value a radio button back to my Redux store using a function, `updateCategory(),` passed as a prop, but I can't get the onChange to fire. Also, how would I pass the value of a radio button as a param instead of typing the value out? I.E. `this.props.updateCategory('health')`

```
 <form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <div className="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label className="btn btn-secondary active">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="options"
          value='health'
          checked={false}
          onChange={() => this.props.updateCategory('health')} /> Health
      </label>
      <label className="btn btn-secondary">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="options"
          value='tattoo'
          checked={true}
          onChange={() => this.props.updateCategory('tattoo')} /> Tattoo
    </label>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a radio button, `onChange` event will trigger for the radio that was `previously checked` as well as the one that is `currently checked`. You can do the following to confirm that the correct radio is checked

```
updateCategory = (e) => {
    if(e.target.checked) {
       this.props.updateCategory(e.target.value)
    }
}

<form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <div className="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label className="btn btn-secondary active">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="options"
          value='health'
          defaultChecked
          checked={this.props.checked === "health" }
          onChange={this.updateCategory} /> Health
    </label>
      <label className="btn btn-secondary">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="options"
          value='tattoo'
          checked={this.props.checked === "tattoo"}
          onChange={this.updateCategory} /> Tattoo
    </label>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Also, you need to make sure that your input is controlled input with the checked value coming from props or state and not a static one, because if you write `checked={true}`, your radio button will always stay true. You need to store the checked state and then update it like

```
checked={this.props.checked}
```

More info about **Controlled Components** can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

---

As an alternative, you can also have the input as uncontrolled components and write them like

```
<form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <div className="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label className="btn btn-secondary active">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="options"
          value='health'
          defaultChecked
          onChange={this.updateCategory} /> Health
    </label>
      <label className="btn btn-secondary">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="options"
          value='tattoo'
          onChange={this.updateCategory} /> Tattoo
    </label>
    </div>
  </form>
```

More info about **[Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag)**.

**[DEMO of Uncontrolled input](https://codesandbox.io/s/mzynnpzwp8)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried your solution and the onChange still does not work. I think it may have something to do with the line '<div className="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">'

Comment: @david , check the update, onChange was firing but since you had the input attribute checked as always a static value, it wasn't changing.

Comment: Thank you! It seems Bootstrap has something to with the onChange not working. When I disabled the import it worked.

Answer (score -2):

```
handleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { name,value } = e.target;
        this.setState({ 
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            });
        }

<form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <div className="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label className="btn btn-secondary active">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="options"
          value='health'
          defaultChecked
          onChange={this.handleChange} /> Health
    </label>
      <label className="btn btn-secondary">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="options"
          value='tattoo'
          onChange={this.handleChange} /> Tattoo
    </label>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Please explain why you believe your code is the answer.